# The application 'msbuild' does not exist error on EF Core command

Tags: .net, .net-core

My os is ubuntu and I have this command for EF Core:

```
dotnet-ef database update --project Payment.Service.Persistence\Payment.Service.Persistence.csproj 
      --startup-project Payment.Service.Presentation\Payment.Service.Presentation.csproj 
      --context Payment.Service.Persistence.PaymentServiceDbContext 
      --configuration Debug --framework net7.0 Initial
```

I got this error

> The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
>
> - You intended to execute a .NET application:
>   The application 'msbuild' does not exist.
> - You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
>   No .NET SDKs were found.
>
> Download a .NET SDK:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
>
> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

This is the output of `dotnet --info` on my machine:

```
Host:
  Version:      7.0.10
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       a6dbb800a4

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: As the error already says, and the output from `dotnet --info` confirms: *No SDKs were found.* .... you need to have the appropriate .NET Core SDK installed on your machine to use the `dotnet` commands

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite obvious: you don't install .NET SDK yet.

The result of dotnet --info already inform you about this:

[image: .NET SDK is not yet installed]